# Will push notification stop working if i use CSR to generate new distribution certificates. ?

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store

Today I got a mail from Apple saying that my distribution certificates will expire soon therefore I have to renew those certificates. The problem which I am facing is that I no longer have access to CSR which I used to create certificates an year ago. I want to know what will happen if I create new certificates with new CSR? Will push notifications work if I will generate new certificates with new CSR and revoke all the old certificates from developer panel and upload newly generated certificates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the difference between using previous CSR and a new one ?**

the CSR contains your private key, that means that none (except you) will be able to use your certificate, unless you export the certificate in .p12 format.

Using a previous CSR simply means that you will use the previous key, so you can share the new certificate without exporting it to .p12 format, because the key will already be known.

If you use a new CSR, you will have to export the certificate in .p12 format.

**What to do**

What you have to do is to create a new Push certificate. Using an old or your new CSR does not matter.

When this is done, simply export your certificate to .p12 format and upload it to the server you're using to send push notification.
You may want to get the same password as the previous p12 (it depends on if you can easily configure that on your server).

Once done, the server will use your new certificate to send push and you can now revoke the previous one (or let it expires).